# How do i generate query url for Amazon SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm going to write a program can post and read messages from SQS with authentication and I've read the document from here
Link: [Query Request Authentication](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/Query_QueryAuth.html)

I have successfully written the process which post a message to specified queue follow by the document. But I always get 403 error when I try to receive message from queue. And I found the signature string rules are different for POST and GET methods.

the signature string is:

```
GET\n
sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\n
/<My Account Id>/<Queue Name>\n
AWSAccessKeyId=<My Access Key>
&Action=ReceiveMessage
&MaxNumberOfMessages=10
&VisibilityTimeout=600
&AttributeName=All
&Expires=2012-04-01T11%3A29%3A24Z
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA1
&SignatureVersion=2
&Version=2011-10-01
```

and the url is

```
https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<My Account Id>/<Queue Name>?
Action=ReceiveMessage
&MaxNumberOfMessages=10
&VisibilityTimeout=600&AttributeName=All
&Version=2011-10-01
&Expires=2012-04-01T11%3A29%3A24Z
&Signature=<BASE64 encoded HmacSHA1 digist with signature string and my security key>
&SignatureVersion=2
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA1
&AWSAccessKeyId=<My Access Key>
```

And I always get the 403 forbidden error:

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-10-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type> 
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>
      The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
    </Message>
    <Detail/>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>16f6e910-62e6-4259-8c09-0358b84cbe60</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Is there anyone can tell me how can I deal with it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you that the signature is being calculated wrong. This is really tough to debug. I spent hours on it the first time I tried it. There's an example signed SQS request at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/MakingRequests_MakingQueryRequestsArticle.html. You should put those parameters in your program, calculate the signature, and try finding bugs into your program creates the same signature.

Specific problems I had, and fixes for them included:

- Sorting the query parameters correctly. They must be in ascending order when creating the string to sign. Your example URL does not show them in order. Did you sort them differently when creating the string to sign?
- URI encoding properly. Every parameter must be URI encoded in the string to sign. Your sample URL does have URI encoding, so this probably isn't your issue. But make sure you're not double-encoding.
- Padding the base64 signature. At least some AWS services insist that the signature be a multiple of four characters long. Two-thirds of the time a base64 encoding will be too short, and need one or two equal signs appended to it. Most base64 encoding libraries do that for you, but not all.

Of course, the easiest thing is to use somebody else's library to make the requests, but what's the fun in that? Good luck debugging this.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely the parameter order: when assembling the signature version 2 string, at the last step the Amazon documentation specifies:

> Add the query string components (the name-value pairs, not including
>   the initial question mark (?) as UTF-8 characters which are URL
>   encoded per RFC 3986 (hexadecimal characters must be uppercased) and
>   sorted using lexicographic byte ordering. Lexicographic byte ordering
>   is case sensitive.

I've spent two days debugging this same "SignatureDoesNotMatch" issue by checking my HMAC, BASE64 and URL encoding procedures and it was just a problem of parameter order.

The documentation should emphasize this issue more; if you use unordered parameter strings (e.g. the same one in the request URL, like those found in the documentation examples), you're going to get this non-intuitive error from the server.